# How to calculate tag cloud based on count between min and max font size?

Tags: javascript, css, svelte

I'm trying to set a min of 100 and a max of 300% font-size in css, but I'm having trouble coming up with the proper calculation:

```
    {#if historyTags.length}
        <h3>Popular jobs searched by users</h3>
        <ul class="tags-list">
            {#each historyTags as tag}
                <li
                    style={`font-size: ${
                        tag.count === minFont ? minFont : (tag.count / maxFont) * (maxFont - minFont) + minFont
                    }%;`}
                >
                    <a href="/searches/history/tags/{tag.word.toLowerCase()}"
                        >{tag.word.toLowerCase()} ({tag.count})</a
                    >
                </li>
            {/each}
        </ul>
    {/if}
```

Font size should be between `100%` and `300%` but I'm getting `1170%`

Answer (score 0):

This entirely depends on the mapping  you want to use. E.g. if want the size to increase linearly with number of uses you need the [linear function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function_(calculus)) equation:

```
f(x) = m * x + t
```

With the two given data points you can determine its constants `m` and `t`:

```
100 = m * min + t
300 = m * max + t

m = (100 - t) / min

300 = ((100 - t) / min) * max + t
t = 300 - ((100 - t) / min) * max
t = 300 - ((100 - t) * max) / min
t = 300 - (100 * max - t * max) / min
t = 300 - ((100 * max) / min - (t * max) / min)
t = 300 - (100 * max) / min + (t * max) / min
t - (t * max) / min = 300 - (100 * max) / min
(t * min) / min - (t * max) / min = 300 - (100 * max) / min
(t * min - t * max) / min = 300 - (100 * max) / min
(t * min - t * max) / min = (300 * min - 100 * max) / min
t * min - t * max = 300 * min - 100 * max
t * (min - max) = 100 * (3 * min - max)
t = 100 * (3 * min - max) / (min - max)

m = (100 - (100 * (3 * min - max) / (min - max))) / min
m = ((100 * (min - max)) / (min - max) - (100 * (3 * min - max) / (min - max))) / min
m = ((100 * (min - max) - (100 * (3 * min - max)) / (min - max))) / min
m = ((100 * (min - max) - (100 * (3 * min - max)) / (min - max))) / min
m = ((100 * min - 100 * max - (300 * min - 100 * max)) / (min - max)) / min
m = ((100 * min - 100 * max - 300 * min + 100 * max) / (min - max)) / min
m = ((-200 * min) / (min - max)) / min
m = (-200 * min) / ((min - max) * min)
m = -200 / (min - max)
```

So the generic formula in relation to the usage counts corresponding to the min and max sizes is:

```
f(x) = (-200 / (min - max)) * x + 100 * (3 * min - max) / (min - max)
```

(The function also outputs values below and above 100/300, so you may need to apply a minimum/maximum.)

[REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/6f94dd2011c9430a9a6db6bd65c9d653?version=3.49.0)

Maybe you want the size to grow more rapidly or fall off instead, then something like a [quadratic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_function) or [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) would be better.

If you fix some or all of the required variables ahead of time, using the equations will not be as complicated. E.g using linear growth, starting at 0 with variable max count you simply get:

```
100 = m * 0 + t
300 = m * max + t

t = 100

300 = m * max + 100
300 - 100 = m * max
m = 200 / max

f(x) = x * (200 / max) + 100
```

Comment: What is m and t?

Comment: The constants that define the shape of a linear function, they are commonly called slope (`m`) and intercept (`t`). If you plot the function on an x/y graph, `t` will be the `y` value at `x = 0`, hence the name.

Comment: I still don't understand how this applies to my code.

Comment: I have given you the formula to correctly calculate the size for the limits given in your question when using linear growth and shown how to derive it. You simply have to use it in your code. See the REPL for a code usage example. In the formula `x` is the input value and corresponds to your `tag.count`. `min`/`max` are the counts at which the size starts/stops to grow. If you need a fully parameterized version of the linear function, that would be `(maxFont - minFont)/(maxCount - minCount) * (x - minCount) + minFont`.

Comment: This works, but its linear. How would I account for one extra small or one extra large number but not be skewed in one direction so much?

Comment: As I said in the answer, there are many possible functions that may be better suited than the linear one, the logistic function for one has falloffs at the extremes. This is all just pure math, you can either try to find a better mapping function and/or e.g. use statistical methods to [detect outliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_detection) and do not use them when determining the min/max parameters of the function.

Comment: Also, there are many tag cloud implementations out there, it shouldn't be too hard to find out how they approach this.